# Issue passing the data from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Overview**:

Passing the data from one form to another.

This is a WinForm application which has two forms, named `form1` and `PostCodeForm`.  I need to pass data from the short-lived form `PostcodeForm` back to Form1 through a `clickEvent`, then close the form. The values are stored into `dataTable` in `PostcodeSearch` class, and to access them I:

1. Loop through dataTable in `PostCodeForm`

   ```
   for (var item = 0; item < retreiveResults.Count; item++)
   {
       var num = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
       dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = retreiveResults[item].City;
       dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = retreiveResults[item].District;
       dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = retreiveResults[item].HouseName;
   ```
2. Created an instance of `Form1` in `PostCodeForm`:

   ```
   Form1 formIndi = new Form1();
   ```
3. Then created some local variables which are initialized just before the end of the loop in `PostCodeForm`

   ```
   var _City_Cell = dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value;
   var _District_Cell = dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value;
   var _HouseName_Cell = dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value;
   ```
4. Then to pass them to `Form1` (in `PostCodeForm`):

   ```
   formIndi.txt_City.Text = _StreetName_Cell.ToString();
   formIndi.txt_HouseName.Text = _HouseName_Cell.ToString();
   formIndi.txt_ District.Text = _District_Cell.ToString();
   ```

I need to pass the data back to the main form and store it in the relevant textBoxes.

**Issue**

My issue is that none of my textBoxes are updating with given values but when I debug the Vars inside the postCodeForm I can see the values, so I have no idea why then the TextBoxes are not displaying the values, as I have always passed data from form to form this way.

Comment: Try Form1 form1 = (this); because you are editing another instantiated form, not the rendered one, i guess

Comment: Please, specify a class name for each of the code snippets. Also, you might want to clarify your naming: what is `PostCodeForm` and how is it different from `PostcodeSearch`? what is `formIndi`?

Comment: @defaultlocale sorry was just a format error its now corrected. `PostcodeSearch `   is `PostcodeForm `  and formIndi is just an instance of Form1

Comment: @Ferus7 using your soloution doesnt work as the form thats instantiated is is not the current form which is PostCodeForm

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe, so link both in two variables as i said, when u instatiate a form by code, you are not rendering it, so the labels are getting empty, because the rendered form has no data binded

Comment: I understand what your saying about its just creating a new instance but how do i render it within the PostCodeForm as the form i need to render is not the current form?

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe Much better, thanks :) Now, to the question itself. What you're saying is that you verified with a debugging tool that on this line `formIndi.txt_City.Text = _StreetName_Cell.ToString();` the `_StreetName_Cell.ToString()` has the value you need. If that's correct, then we have to assume that something overwrites `txt_City.Text` after this line.

Comment: @defaultlocale  yes thats correct as Ferus7 mentioned its becuase im creating a new instance not rendering the current form. So I need to findout how to render the current form PostCodeForm

Comment: ahh I see :) @Ferus7 you should turn your comment into an answer, by the way

Answer (score 3):

As @Ferus7 pointed out you're creating a new instance of `Form1` instead of updating the values in your main form.

```
//new instance with new text boxes and values
Form1 formIndi = new Form1();
//updates the control in the new form, doesn't affect the caller.
formIndi.txt_City.Text = _StreetName_Cell.ToString();
```

If you want to retrieve values from `PostcodeForm`, there're multiple ways to do that. One option is to declare properties/methods in `PostcodeForm` and to retrieve values through them:

```
//declaration in PostcodeForm
class PostcodeForm {
//...
public string StreetName {get; private set;}

//after data retrieval
StreetName = _StreetName_Cell.ToString();


//call PostcodeForm from Form1
postcodeForm = new PostcodeForm();
postcodeForm.ShowDialog();
//after that, get the value
txt_City.Text = postcodeForm.StreetName;
```

Another way is to pass the reference of `Form1` to `PostcodeForm`:

```
class PostcodeForm {
//declare field
private final Form1 parent;
//create a constructor that accepts `Form1`
PostcodeForm(Form1 parent) 
{
    this.parent = parent;
    //... (InitializeComponents, etc.)
}

//update parent as necessary
parent.txt_City.Text = postcodeForm.StreetName;


//Sample call from Form1
postcodeForm = new PostcodeForm(this);
postcodeForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Render the new instance form

```
Form1 PostCodeForm= new Form1();
PostCodeForm.Show();
Application.Run();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but Im still confused with this if i Implement this into my Form PostCodeForm as it still creates a new instance of form1